# Write 1 SQL query to combine 3 independent tables with functions: group by and case when

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables as follows:

Table school_a with 4 columns:

```
date: (2020-11-31,...)  
note: (20, 30, 40,...)  
home: (23.45, 45.34, 65.67, ...)  
id: (54326, 87332, ...)
```

Table school_b with 4 columns:

```
time: (2020-11-31,...)  
grade: (34, 54, 34,...)   
homework: (12.32, 34.65,...)   
user: ('student', 'professor', 'student',...)
```

Table school_c with 4 columns:

```
day:  (2020-11-31,...)  
number: (34, 54, 34,...)  
amount: (10.24 AGE, 11.25 AGE, 12.63 AGE, ...)    
title: ('54934-ST-string-student-str.st', '54934-ST-string-teacher-str.st',....)
```

Sorry for the table presentation but it is not easy to put in a table format.

I created a SQL query to calculate what I need for each table but I do not succeed to combine the 3 queries in one. I cannot figure out the logic that I need to use to combine it.

Here is my SQL code for each table:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(home/note) AS kpi,   
    CASE     
       WHEN id IN (34564, 87423, 89076, 32145, 87653) THEN 'Student'     
       WHEN id IN (67543, 87413, 78996, 34215 ) THEN 'Teacher'     
       ELSE 'Other'      
    END AS role   
FROM school_a     
WHERE date >= '2020-08-01' AND date <= '2020-08-31'    
GROUP BY role     

SELECT 
    SUM(grade)/COUNT(user) AS kpi,    
    CASE     
       WHEN user = 'Student' THEN 'Student'     
       WHEN user = 'Professor' THEN 'Teacher'        
       ELSE 'Other'      
    END AS role     
FROM school_b      
WHERE time >= '2020-08-01' AND time <= '2020-08-31'    
GROUP BY role     


SELECT 
    SUM((REPLACE(amount,' AGE',''))/number) AS kpi,   
    CASE     
       WHEN title IN ('41320 - ST-STtr-Student-str.st', '89064 - ST-stRst-str-strr user-strr.str/blablabla/strstr') THEN 'Student'   
       WHEN title IN ('43789 - ST-STred-Teacher-stee.str', '65283-CH-strstrs-teacher-strr.str--STR') THEN 'Teacher'     
       ELSE 'Other'     
    END AS role    
FROM school_c     
WHERE day >= '2020-08-01' AND day <= '2020-08-31'    
GROUP BY role
```

As you understand I need to measure the kpi for each table that have different columns names and different columns meaning for the full month of August 2020.

When I run separately each query I got what I need now I would like to combine all the 3 queries into one. If I create only one query I got a message such as

> Error: ambiguous column name: role

Any feedback to improve my current queries is welcome. Thanks for reading.

----- Edited to clarify the result

The expected result is a table with 2 columns (role and kpi) and 3 rows (Student, Teacher, Other).
Using "union" I got almost what I want: 2 columns (role and kpi) and more than 3 rows as the grouping is school and then role. I want only the role and sum the kpi per role.

Comment: What is "combine"? Please, provide sample output

Comment: This is the first time that I ask a question on SO.
Thank you to the various contributors for making my question readable.

Comment: What is the "combine" query you use? cause i think you can simply just `union all` since every table got only [kpi] [role] two col.

Comment: Note that `SUM(grade)/COUNT(user)` can be replaced with `avg(grade)` (assuming `user` can never be null)

Comment: I edited my question. @astentx I would like to run in one sql query the 3 queries I have written in my question. The expected result is two columns with 3 rows for each role and corresponding kpi.

Comment: @Peter union all worked as union and the result is almost what I want. I need to group by role. Currently what I get is a grouping by school and role and I only need a role grouping.

Comment: Change done for AVG @a_horse_with_no_name thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to simply UNION the different outputs?

```
SELECT SUM(home/note) AS kpi,   
CASE     
WHEN id IN (34564, 87423, 89076, 32145, 87653) THEN 'Student'     
WHEN id IN (67543, 87413, 78996, 34215 ) THEN 'Teacher'     
ELSE 'Other'      
END AS role   
FROM school_a     
WHERE date >= '2020-08-01' AND date <= '2020-08-31'    
GROUP BY role     

UNION

SELECT SUM(grade)/COUNT(user) AS kpi,    
CASE     
WHEN user = 'Student' THEN 'Student'     
WHEN user = 'Professor' THEN 'Teacher'     
ELSE 'Other'      
END AS role     
FROM school_b      
WHERE time >= '2020-08-01' AND time <= '2020-08-31'    
GROUP BY role     

UNION

SELECT SUM((REPLACE(amount,' AGE',''))/number) AS kpi,   
CASE     
WHEN title IN ('41320 - ST-STtr-Student-str.st', '89064 - ST-stRst-str-strr user-strr.str/blablabla/strstr') THEN 'Student'   
WHEN title IN ('43789 - ST-STred-Teacher-stee.str', '65283-CH-strstrs-teacher-strr.str--STR') THEN 'Teacher'     
ELSE 'Other'     
END AS role    
FROM school_c     
WHERE day >= '2020-08-01' AND day <= '2020-08-31'    
GROUP BY role
```

I haven't done any checks in any way but as long as the columns match it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I got almost the expected result. I have two columns role (Student, Teacher, Other) and the kpi for each role. The result is per school: school a/school b/school c. How do I do if I want the grouping by role without taking into account the school grouping?

Comment: Any idea where I need to add the change to be able to get the grouping by role only and not anymore by school? @thommy

Comment: @Isa Just select from this `union` and do `group by`

Comment: @Isa Like stated by other comments just select from the union output and do the group by outside the union.

`SELECT * FROM
(
UNIONS GOES HERE
) as output
GROUP BY output.role`